# Failed to copy JAR from build folder Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to copy my jar file in my docker file, but, it's not working.

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder264149867/build/libs/create-account-service.0.0.1.jar: no such file or directory
```

this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
# This environment variable will be added to all log messages shipped to Logstash
ENV APPLICATION_NAME=create-account-service

COPY ./build/libs/create-account-service.0.0.1.jar create-account-service.0.0.1.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /create-account-service-0.0.1.jar"]
```

I already did gradlew build and the jar is inside build/libs

Comment: I also tried this COPY build/libs/*.jar create-account-service.0.0.1.jar

Comment: Can you double-check the filename: should there be `.` or `-` in between the name `create-account-service` and version `0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your jar has proper permissions to be copied? Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know If this is the exact issue But you are not giving location to copy u r giving the jar file which is not yet there is your image can this be the problem
`COPY ./build/libs/create-account-service.0.0.1.jar create-account-service.0.0.1.jar`

Syntax of copy 
`cp SOURCE DEST
cp SOURCE DIRECTORY
cp SOURCE1 SOURCE2 SOURCE3 SOURCEn DIRECTORY
cp [OPTION] SOURCE DEST
cp [OPTION] SOURCE DIRECTORY`